# Textarea not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea, but it only lets me click on it (so that I can start typing) at the bottom.  However, the text appears at the proper place.

The website can be found here: http://ibdesigns.net23.net/.

The problem is in the "Contact" circle in the field labeled "Request".  It only allows you to click on the textarea at the very bottom.

Comment: It seems like the lightbox is preventing me from clicking the top of the text.

Comment: Have you tried giving it a high z-index?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `<div id="circles">` that is absolutely positioned over the textarea, and it intercepts the clicks over the upper part of the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

the circle div is covering the textarea.

```
#circles {
width: 940px;
height: 180px;
left: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 155px;
}
```

reduce the width of the circle div

Answer (score 0):

There's a `div` with an `id` of "circles" which is floating above most of the `textarea`.  At first glance the `div` doesn't seem to be doing anything, but it contains some stuff that I assume may be dynamically used on the page.

Style the `div` to no longer be in the way and you should be fine.

For reference, you can easily discover things like this with browser debugging tools.  In Safari I right-clicked on the "problem area" and chose "Inspect Element."  The browser showed me the `div`, highlighted it for me, and showed me all the CSS related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just add:

```
textarea {
    z-index: 1000000;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is neither the Div nor the Circle. 
A few changes in your CSS should fix this.

```
#selected {
    width: 78px;
    height: 66px;
    top: 18px;
    background: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 578px;
    border-radius: 36px;
}
```

You may select your background color using Firefox plugin Color Picker to get this working. Do not use a background image for that div and add radius to it. This should solve your problem